# Adjust MSChart Y Labels after drawn

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

The problem im having with MSChart is that I am needing to adjust my Y axis label values after they have been drawn.

Here is how I plot my chart

```
foreach(Int16 data in array)
{
   chart.Series["MySeries"].Points.AddXY(i, data);
   i++;
}
```

After I have drawn up all elelemt of my array I am needing to adjust the Y-Axis Label values.

- Currently the data is ranging from 0 - 300.
- I am neededin to adjust the Y axis label from 0 - 300 to -150 to 150.
- Actual data values potted to remain the same, just edit the label values.

I have tried adding customLabel after this foreach statement but the same old Y-axis label (0-300) is still shown.
Im wanting the Can anyone please help me.

Thanks so much in advance"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of .AddXY(i, data) do this:

```
chart.Series["MySeries"].Points.AddXY(i, data - 150);
```

Comment: I need to divide the data, by 41, and because its of int16, if I divide it caused the graph layout to become very sharp. Hence the rason I need to alter the label values. Do you know also how I could change my X-Axis to show 1 second for every 170 data samples read? att he minite its plotting 1 second for every i element

Comment: How does altering labels help you make values less sharp?
For making 1 second interval you should:
1. Set interval on X-Axis to 1.0;
2. Pass (Double)i / 170 to AddXY method instead of i.

Comment: Hello Loki! Thanks for the tips, can I please ask a few things.

Comment: I got that to work perfect, only thing is im using a scroll bar to view my data in 10 sec frames, when I scroll through the data for the FIRST time, the x-axis is messed up. goes from 0 -10 to 9.994  to 19.994, yet if I click to scroll back to beginning then forward again it goes from 0 - 10 to 10 - 20 and will continue to work properly after that, any idea why this o happens on first click? I really cant figure it out:( any advice would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: Sure, you are welcome! Could you show your calculations code? Probably that is happening because of floating point operations (it's precision is limited and after series of operations precision errors sum up and may become pretty large - about .006 in this case). The solution could be in either rearranging operations or using System.Decimal type instead of Double (System.Decimal has better precision). Anyway, could you show your calculations?